# select data from combobox and show the id in label c#

Tags: select, combobox, label

I have a combo box with nationality Text I want to show the selected value id of the nationality in the label.text
I did it this way

```
lblNathonality.text=comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

could someone tell me what is wrong here ?????!!!! 
I'm lost    it did not work and I do not know how to fix this problem could someone write the code in Linq please help I can't solve it !!!!!!!!!

Comment: it works for me, what kind of item collection did you set in your combo box ?

Comment: You should tell us what's wrong, does it not work; do you get an error?

Comment: it did not work and I do not know how to fix this problem could someone write the code in Linq please help I can't solve it !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem.

lblNathonality.text= Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue);

Comment: it does not work I can't see the Id in the label the code also did not work

Comment: I want to show the id of the selected combo box value in the label